# Setting custom alarms in Outlook 2010

Tags: microsoft-outlook, calendar

I'm wondering whether it's possible out-of-the-box to set custom alarms for meetings/appointments that are imported via an external ical calendar file into Outlook?  Use the built-in notification system, since it's that robust.  I cant' seem to find any settings relating to external calendars.

Also, if this is possible, is it also possible to set the alarms for all events in that calandar to a custom date?  I see that Outlook is scriptable via VB for rules, would they also work for calendars?

Thanks!